# Download location for Android 4.4 x86 (64bit)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-x86

Where can we download following
 Android 4.4 ISO
 Android 4.4 64bit ISO

I have checked at following location
https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list

Seems like android-x86 4.3 is the maximum version provided there.

I am searching for ISO to set it up on VM Player/Virtual Box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there are no Android 4.4 images ready yet for this. In the [download area](http://www.android-x86.org/download) of the Android X86 project you can find a couple of images and more, starting with Android 1.6 (Donut) and currently reaching up to Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean), and also other useful resources. Might be worth checking there again later, as I would expect they add 4.4 as soon as they have an image ready for that.

I'm not sure whether the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) project (the "next generation" of AndroidVM) offers some image downloads as well, as checking would require one to sign-up first. *Genymotion* is another VM solution, which AFAIK works together with VirtualBox. It should be quite fast and stable, is based on Android x86, and available for MacOS, Linux, and Windows alike.

---

**EDIT (2014-10-31):** The [download-area](http://www.android-x86.org/download) now holds the 4.4 images. A second place to check is [the project's downloads at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/), which currently also have the 4.4 images available.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to www.androidx86.org and click on releases, it will direct you to a list of releases that can be downloaded.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/Release%204.4/ is where the Android x86 4.4 RC2 ISO is one such link that androidx86.org will direct you to.

Answer (score 0):

The [Genymotion web site](https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc) says, speaking of Android 4.4, "We are finishing baking this hot new flavour... Be ready!". As of this post Android 4.4 is not yet available via Genymotion or AndroidX86 to my knowledge, although both claim to be working on it.

Answer (score 0):

> The x86 Android* 4.4 (KitKat) emulator system image enables you to run
>   an emulation of Android on your development machine. In combination
>   with the Android SDK, you can test your Android applications on a
>   virtual Android device based on Intel Architecture.

Source: [Android* 4.4 (KitKat) x86 Emulator System Image](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-4-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link for Android 4.4 :

[android-x86-4.4-RC2.iso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/Release%204.4/android-x86-4.4-RC2.iso/download**)

Android X86 is still in beta, the above link will give you RC2. On 8/8/2014, they released version R1.

You can always go to http://www.android-x86.org to check for new updates.