# Where do I get Android L iso for x86 environment?

Tags: android-x86, 5.0-lollipop

My question is much similar to this question: [Download location for Android 4.4 x86 (64bit)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/57113/51292)

Basically, I want to get Android L(a.k.a Lollipop, 5.0) iso for x86 architecture, so as to run it in VM. But I can't find anything newer than 4.3 anywhere on the web, so how do I get it?

Comment: 4.3 (Jelly Bean) was the last ISO put on web. I think you need to wait for some more time...

Comment: @MANI basically correct, but [The Android-x86 4.4-r1 released](http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-4-4-r1) at 2014-08-08 already :) Files are now [at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/) it seems. But yes: 5.x is just picking its egg shells, will take a little longer to make it over :)

Comment: @Izzy How longer that would be? 1 year? or even more? BTW why does it take so longer to make the builds? at least it isn't the case with building other Linux OSes.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - We cannot estimate the time here. But it may take a long time for sure.

Comment: My crystal ball is just out for repair, so I cannot tell you a date. It's more to it then just "trigger the build": sources have to be ported between different architectures here (ARM vs. x86), which can be quite a tedious job. // @MANI Anytime! I just happened to know as I've read about it recently ;)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the links above. BTW crystal ball repair is twice as expensive now. +1

Comment: Working x86 iso for android 5.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Z0gX3JlBnHZkI5SDFLX25fSGs/view

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why all the answers are giving you the run around, it's very easy to download the source and get the iso generated.

Here it is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VR-WNTOX0qVnkyWExEZHdLTms/view

Comment: Could you tell me how to create the iso?(possibly a link if it's too long story) It would be great to also learn how to catch the fish than just having one.

Comment: this is a source of an iso but the links does not work.

Comment: Please provide an updated link, keeps saying its down. -1 until fixed.

Comment: The link works, but the system hangs on logo screen (both while booting from CD or after installation on disk) with 100% CPU load and without disk activity.

Comment: There is an [open issue for this](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/issues/detail?id=1682). BTW, [Android 5.1 image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B43N_UcsJhpjNXZHQVVJaXJaWjQ) has the same problem. PS. I'm trying it under VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 2):

> so as to run it in VM

Why not use the SDK emulator? It has Android 5.0 images for Intel x86 and even x64 architectures.

Dowload the SDK from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i) and extract it to a folder you like. Now launch SDK Manager and add the Lollipop images.

[image]

You will also need Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager driver if you will be using the x86 emulator. Get it from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager).

Go to the folder where you extracted the SDK archive, then from `sdk/tools` folder launch via `cmd` the virtual device manager. Type in `cmd`: `android avd`. Create the x86 virtual device:

[image]

Maybe you should use the same amount of RAM as you selected when installed Intel HAXM driver.

Start the device from AVD Manager using the **Start** button.

[image]

Comment: Concerning the "why": speed/performance would be a good reason. The SDK emulator is not known to be brilliant in that context ;) Apart from that: valid solution :)

Comment: @Izzy indeed, it runs awfully with 768 MB RAM :( It would be interesting to know if the x86 images could somehow be run on another virtualisation tool (like KVM or VirtualBox).

Comment: I'm not talking about the RAM you assign to the VM, but about the emulator in general: regardless of how much RAM you assing the VM, other emulators performing way better AFAIK ;)

Comment: @Cornelius  I just used x86 iso Kitkat in virtualbox couple date 's ago.  It works very well -   Much faster than emulator.   Time to boot up android is like bootup normal linux system with GUI.    Not sure why google doesn't use that instead of emulator.

Comment: I asked the same question but for x64 iso, here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/97569/10658

Comment: Emulator doesn't support USB