# Where to get or create an Android Lollipop iso for x64 environment?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, stock-android, dual-boot, android-pc, lenovo-yoga

My question is simular to [this question about iso for x86.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86079/where-do-i-get-android-l-iso-for-x86-environment)

I am looking to dual-boot my Lenovo Yoga 3 pro with Android L and I need an x64 iso. 
I can not use an x86 as it is not able to install to my hard disk partitioned with GPT.
Where can I find an Andorid L x64 iso?

I am willing to try to create an iso on my own. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Android Lollipop or another flavor of Android on your x64 laptop I recommend to use an Android disto called [RemixOS](http://www.jide.com/remixos). They have 64-bit support. There is another Android project called [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/en/download_x86) that is similar but only x86.